# Regex String Mail

Tags: regex, email

I have the following string: `test@gmail.com, test@gmail.com <test@gmail.com>, Test Gmail <test@gmail.com>, Test, Gmail <test@gmail.com>`.

I would like to use a regex to obtain the following result in an array :

```
test@gmail.com,
test@gmail.com <test@gmail.com>,
Test Gmail <test@gmail.com>,
Test, Gmail <test@gmail.com>
```

It is unfortunately not possible to use the comma as separator because it can be included in the string preceding the email (ex : Test, Gmail <test@gmail.com>

Comment: What programming language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'd use an existing library otherwise you end up with things like https://regex101.com/library/31plIS

Comment: I am using php for my regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((?>(?:\w+@\w+\.\w+)|(?:[^<>\n]+))(?> ?<(?:\w+@\w+\.\w+)>)?)(?:, )?`

This will match your sample strings as you have written them.

- `(?>(?:\w+@\w+\.\w+)|(?:[^<>\n]+))` Match either an email, or some string of characters that does not have `<`, `>`, or `\n` in it, checking first for the email.
- `(?> ?<(?:\w+@\w+\.\w+)>)?` Optionally match another email (with an optional space in front of it).
- `(?:, )?` Optionally match a comma and a space.

Note that this will do nothing to **validate** whether the captured string is a correctly formatted email; it will only collect strings that look like them, and even then, will only do so only for the format of the specific input you've provided in your example.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/TXLItx/1/)

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: I'd imagined a comprehensive email solution was big, but had no idea the regex was *that* big. Hopefully the limited-scope answer I provided is enough for OP's purposes. Thank you for the links, bookmarked.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, I would only have to change the mail regex which is not perfect. Thank you very much !